# externalize spring datasource properties for docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource

I want to be able to override

```
spring.datasource.url
spring.datasource.user
spring.datasource.password
```

on each application start using environment variables;

That's because I'm trying to dockerize application and database. 
I want to specify `url, user, password` in .env file (for docker-compose)
and share them with application container (connect to db) and db-container (to be able to connect).

I tried

```
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=${url}
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_USER=${user}
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=${password}
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

But it seems to pick up only the last param (password in this case)

Also i tried

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run \
  -Dspring.datasource.url=${url} \
  -Dspring.datasource.user=${user} \
  -Dspring.datasource.password=${passwrod} \
```

but this one seem to care only about the first one (url in this case).

I really want to know if there is any viable method to achieve that 
via terminal or do I actually have to override properties file each time?

**UPDATE**

The problem was indeed in me. 
It's `spring.datasource.` `username`, not `user`. Really sorry for waisting time on that.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something wrong because I have used both methods and they work properly.

Comment: @Deadron Totally, I’ve spent last 3 hours trying to figure out what exactly is wrong. Did you try to remove all three properties from application.yml? Because it work fine if I leave 2 of the there and pass the 3rd one as param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using maven to execute your spring boot app which is the cause of at least some of your problems.

When you specify a -D argument while using maven it is passing system arguments to maven not to your spring app. If you read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-system-properties.html it shows you need to use the syntax

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dproperty1=overridden"
```

The easy answer is dont use maven to execute your spring boot app. Produce a jar and execute it with java -jar

Comment: This way I get the same results. Hibernate is trying to authenticate ‘artemvrby’ (which is my local user) instead of datasource user that I specify

Comment: Sounds like an interaction with your shell then. There is nothing in maven or hibernate or spring that is going to know how to retrieve your local user name.

Answer (score 1):

Do any of your values contain perhaps a space, or other shell busting character? Quotes are your friend here

---

Does a more basic `java -jar target/project.jar -Dspring.datasource.url=...` do anything different?

On the `export SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL ...` variant, can you properly `echo $SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` and get the expected value back? For all the env variables?

If you use simple values like `XXX` and `YYY` instead of real values, does that do anything different?

Trying to distinguish between the mechanism and the data...

---

Are the `${url}`, `${user}` and `${password}` (or `${passwrod}` even) literal (eg: env variables themselves) or just elided here for brevity?

Comment: No, ther all are single word (except url, which is jdbc:post...., but url works fine)

Comment: I've noticed that it fails only to set user. Hibernate is trying to authenticate my local mac user, instead of spring.datasource.user if I don't specify that in application.yml. Password and url are fine

Comment: ${url}, ${user} and ${password} are here for brevity

Answer (score 1):

There just was a typo. It's `spring.datasource.` `username`, not `user` (or `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME`). Really sorry for waisting time on that.